# Parallax; Find the length of the common hypotenuse of two right triangles

Tags: trigonometry

I'm attempting to calculate the distance between two objects based on parallax/triangulation, but I could only find solutions applying to Astronomy, where the triangles are always isosceles. This is how I've formulated the problem:

[image: Included diagram]

Points $P$ and $Q$ represent two different view points from which points $A$ and $D$ are observed. $A$ is my reference point, and so both lengths $\overline{PA}$ and $\overline{QA}$ are known. At point $P$ I measure the length $\overline{DB}$, which is the perpendicular to $\overline{PA}$, and at point $Q$ I measure the length $\overline{AC}$, which is the perpendicular to $\overline{QD}$. I also know the angle $\angle PAQ$. With only this information, I'd like to determine the length $\overline{AD}$, which is also the common hypotenuse of both right triangles formed by $ABD$ and $ACD$, for any point $D$.

I'm not sure if this even has a solution the way it's been formulated here, but it feels like it should. If either of $B$ or $C$ is mirrored over $\overline{AD}$ then the points $ABCD$ form a cyclic quadrilateral with $\overline{AD}$ as one of the diagonals. This gives a bunch of complicated relations which I'm not entirely sure are useful.

In the special case where point $D$ lies within the triangle $PAQ$ then I can apply the solution given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855233/how-can-i-calculate-the-angles-of-two-ra-triangles-with-a-shared-common-hypotenu) using $PAQ$ as the total angle. But I can't find how to generalize this solution.

EDIT: Turns out the problem is ill-posed. I can solve it by knowing angles $\angle DPA$ and $\angle DQA$. I'll post an updated diagram when I can.