# Finding angles with shared hypotenuse

Tags: geometry

I have two RA triangles with a shared common hypotenuse. Given the lengths of the opposite sides of the two right-angle triangles, $a_1$ and $a_2$, and the sum of both angles, $\theta$, how can I calculate each angle, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$?
Mick answered a similar inquiry years ago but with known adjacent sides but I have known opposite sides.
Thanks.

Comment: Define $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$? It may be useful to provide a link to the similar question you mention.

Comment: Here it is:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855233/how-can-i-calculate-the-angles-of-two-ra-triangles-with-a-shared-common-hypotenu?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$c=\frac{a_1}{\sin \theta_1}=\frac{a_2}{\cos \theta_2}=\frac{a_2}{\cos (\theta - \theta_1)}$$

Rearrange,

$$\frac{a_2}{a_1} = \cos\theta\cot\theta_1  +\sin\theta$$

Solve for the angle $\theta_1$

$$\cot\theta_1 = \frac{a_2}{a_1} \sec\theta -\tan\theta\implies
\theta_1=\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{a_2}{a_1} \sec\theta -\tan\theta\right)$$

and then $\theta_2=\theta - \theta_1$.